# Create PHP extension in C

Tags: php, c, visual-studio-2010, php-extension

I got struck with creating PHP extenstions in C code.  I have already referred the links and followed the steps they have given:

http://netindonesia.net/blogs/risman/archive/2008/06/15/part-2-writing-php-extension

http://devzone.zend.com/303/extension-writing-part-i-introduction-to-php-and-zend/

Still I got the problem to create a extension.

I am using the XAMPP with PHP version 5.4.16 in Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010 Professional to create and compile C++ code.

I am using the following C++ code:

```
 #include "stdio.h"
 #include "stdafx.h"
 /* declaration of functions to be exported */
 ZEND_FUNCTION(DoubleUp);

/* compiled function list so Zend knows what's in this module */
zend_function_entry FirstPHPExtModule_functions[] = {
     ZEND_FE(DoubleUp, NULL)
     {NULL, NULL, NULL}
};

/* compiled module information */
zend_module_entry FirstPHPExtModule_module_entry = {
     STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
     "FirstPHPExt Module",
     FirstPHPExtModule_functions,
     NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
     NO_VERSION_YET, STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES
};

/* implement standard "stub" routine to introduce ourselves to Zend */
ZEND_GET_MODULE(FirstPHPExtModule)

/* DoubleUp function */
/* This method takes 1 parameter, a long value, returns the value multiplied by 2 */
ZEND_FUNCTION(DoubleUp){
   long paramValue = 0;
   if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "l", &paramValue) == FAILURE) {
       RETURN_STRING("Bad parameters!", true);
   }
   paramValue *= 2;
   RETURN_LONG(paramValue);
}
```

But, I got the error as below:

```
 1>php_myclass.cpp(16): error C2065: 'ZEND_DEBUG' : undeclared identifier
 1>
 1>Build FAILED.
```

Please help me to create a PHP Extension in windows 7 environment.

Comment: Have you set `ZEND_DEBUG=0` on the "preprocessor defines" (or whatever it is called) in your project?

Comment: Yes, I have set it as ZEND_DEBUG=0

Comment: I would double check that. Check also that you have it set for both release and debug builds - I've more than once set it for one of the two, then scratched my head sore because I can't understand why it's "not working".

[Or do what bizzehdee says]

Answer (score 0):

define `ZEND_DEBUG=0` in your project defines, or project properties depending on what it is you are using. Or, in stdafx.h, set

```
#ifndef ZEND_DEBUG
#define ZEND_DEBUG 0
#endif
```

And if you are using visual studio

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define ZEND_DEBUG 1
#else
#define ZEND_DEBUG 0
#endif
```

So if you build in debug mode, the zend debug code makes it in, and building in release removes all zend debug code.

NB: Make sure you also have `ZTS=1`, `ZEND_WIN32` and `PHP_WIN32` defined in your project.

Follow this guide for setting up the correct environment for building php extensions with visual studio [visual studio build guide](http://blog.slickedit.com/2007/09/creating-a-php-5-extension-with-visual-c-2005/). Its for VC2005, but it is more or less the same process.

Comment: If I have set as you have mentioned, then I am getting the following errors:    1>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(990,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(c:\users\kumar.annamalai\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FirstPHPExt\Debug\FirstPHPExt.dll) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (c:\users\kumar.annamalai\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FirstPHPExt\Debug\MyPHP-Custom.dll). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values .... etc...

Comment: Have you already created defines for `ZTS=1`, `ZEND_WIN32` and `PHP_WIN32` in your project?

Comment: Also, if you read the error, it tells you how to fix it "To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values"

Comment: Hi Bizzehdee, Thanks for reply, your hints works fine, but I am getting new error.  1>e:\xampp\bin\tsrm\readdir.h(10): warning C4005: '_WIN32_WINNT' : macro redefinition

Comment: have you defined `_WIN32_WINNT` in stdafx.h yourself? if so, wrap it in a `#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT #endif`

Comment: Now I am getting the error: 1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\sys/utime.inl(37): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\sys/utime.inl(42): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\sys/utime.inl(47): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\sys/utime.inl(76): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0

Comment: this is now a general C question that could be solved by reading a guide: http://blog.slickedit.com/2007/09/creating-a-php-5-extension-with-visual-c-2005/